# Get random firebase database entry

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got users like this inside my database:

```
users
--45jklj4kljfejlk34 // random uid
----id: 1 // I add this manually when creating a user (maybe it helps getting a random user)
----someData: true
--454jkljkljefnd4lk
----id: 2
----someData: true
```

I want to get a random user, but I don't know how.
I tried sth. like this:

```
let usersCount = DataService.sharedInstance.DB_USER_COUNT
let rand = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(usersCount))) + 1
let userRef = DataService.sharedInstance.DB_REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "id").queryStarting(atValue: rand).queryLimited(toFirst: 1))
```

I get usersCount from the database. There, I increment the figure every time I add a user.

But this doesn't work. This is what I get if I printed this:

```
(/users {
    i = id;
    l = 1;
    sp = 1;
    vf = l;
})
```

Any suggestions, how I can achieve this?

Comment: use it like `DataService.sharedInstance.DB_REF_USERS.queryStarting(atValue: rand).queryLimited(toFirst: 1))`

Comment: Hm, that prints the same strange stuff

Comment: ran it a couple of times and it printed always the same `(/users {
    l = 1;
    sp = 1;
    vf = l;
})`

Comment: hm, it's only returning 1

Comment: so it always gives you same value if it returns same value... :)

Comment: Okay, I will look into that :D But let's say I fixed it. It still gives me this nonsense array from above and not a user or something. Or do I have to do something with it?

Comment: you have to put observer on that query after that it will give you a value from database

Comment: okay, thank you, I will try that

Comment: Okay, I tried adding an observer but it gives me an empty snapshot

Comment: `DataService.sharedInstance.DB_REF_USERS.queryStarting(atValue: rand).queryLimited(toFirst: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        })`

Comment: still `Optional(<null>)`

Comment: make a simple query first `DataService.sharedI‌​nstance.DB_REF_USERS.‌​queryOrdered(byChild: "id").observeSingleEven‌​t(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in print(snapshot) }) `

Comment: that returns all users, though they aren't ordered by id

Comment: use equalTo query with random id

Comment: tried it, still returns null :/

Comment: I found a workaround. I'll post an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as firebase works quite differently than relational based databases, redundancies seem acceptable in order to be fast and efficient. So I came up with a workaround that works for me.

When I create a user I add him to the "users" tree. Additionally, I add him to a "numUsers" tree (I'm terrible at choosing names, sorry for that). This looks like that:

```
users
--45jklj4kljfejlk34 // random uid
----id: 1
----someData: true
--454jkljkljefnd4lk
----id: 2
----someData: true

numUsers
--1: 45jklj4kljfejlk34
--2: 454jkljkljefnd4lk
```

So, "numUsers" consists of an `id` as key and the `uid` as value. Every time I add a new user, I grab the "usersCount" (which I incremented by 1 before) and use it as key.

This way, I can easily grab a random user by using this:

```
DataService.sharedInstance.DB_REF_USERS.child("\(rand)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in print(snapshot) })
```